# Regex expression for date

Tags: c#, regex

Anyone got an idea how to write expression for date format DDMMYY
for example:
("130488"      13-date, 04-month, 88-year),
("311290"      31-date, 12-month, 90-year)

Comment: @GregS I have tried this one: ^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])[0-9]{2}$

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to see the date fields validated outside the regex, but this will do what you want

```
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:[0-9]{2})
```

Comment: this doesnt accept when I enter month like 01, 02...,11,12 but it accepts month when month is 20, 21, 22...

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are seeing. My regex passes 010200 and rejects 012000. Can you give a specific example please?

Comment: I had a little mistake in the code, but now I have fixed it and this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should do :

```
[0-3][0-9][0-1][0-9]{3}
```

Comment: Not really. '000000` isn't a date that I recognize.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[0-9]{2}
```

That should restrict matches to the correctnumeric range for each component, but it will still allow some dogdy matches - like the 31st of Feb, for example.

You could try something insane like:

```
((0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])02|(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)(0[469]|11)|(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])(0[13578]|1[02]))[0-9]{2}
```

Unless I've screwed that up completely (which is **highly** likely) that will only match valid dates except for 29th Feb in non-leap years.  Good luck catering for that!

Comment: Touche Andrew! But yours is missing a closing bracket after `[0-2]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you made the question more complex.

If you want the check the string is valid for a date, you can use the function below (if you use C#):

```
    public static bool IsDateValid(string datestr)
    {
        bool IsValid = false;
        if (datestr.Length == 6)
        {
            try
            {
                new DateTime(Convert.ToInt16(datestr.Substring(0, 2)), Convert.ToInt16(datestr.Substring(2, 2)), Convert.ToInt16(datestr.Substring(4)));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                IsValid = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            IsValid = false;
        }
        return IsValid;
    }
```